# Query works, but not in function

Tags: postgresql, function

I've been trying to get this to work in a function.   It works from command line only:

```
SELECT d.cta_id, d.cta_name, d.cta_marketing_text, d.cta_text,
       c.category_id, c.category_name,
       d.cta_link, d.adid, d.product_type, d.global_cta, d.active_flag,
       TO_CHAR(d.date_created,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS date_created,
       TO_CHAR(d.date_modified,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS date_modified,
       TO_CHAR(p.placement_date,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS placement_date
FROM cta_article_data d
JOIN (SELECT p.cta_id, p.placement_date
      FROM cta_placement_dates p
      WHERE p.placement_date = CURRENT_DATE) AS p
  ON d.cta_id = p.cta_id
JOIN (SELECT c.category_id, c.category_name
      FROM categories c) AS c
  ON c.category_id = ANY(STRING_TO_ARRAY(d.category_id,',')::int[]);

SELECT retrieve_cta_data();

ON d.cta_id = p.cta_id'" returned 3 columns
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function retrieve_current_cta() line 10 at assignment
```

I'm really stuck here if anyone can spot anything.

Comment: You see the error message it gives me.   I do not know what that means.

Comment: @Landon, adding a SQL you use to create a function would be beneficial.

Comment: The code of the function is more than it will allow in this comment window.   But basically the query I have you, returning a table type, and opened by RETURN QUERY EXECUTE

Comment: You say the SQL runs ok from command line. That means the problem is in the way it is used in function. You can use https://justpaste.it/ or any other online sharing platform to provide full text of the function `retrieve_current_cta`. A script to create tables used in the function is also very welcome.